# Contact form with file uploader solution

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm building a website (no CMS or framework) that needs a contact form with a file uploader. I've already written a PHP script for a standalone contact form, but I'm not sure how to go about connecting it with a file uploader that will store the files on the server and will also work on mobile devices.

Since I'm not very experienced in this topic, my questions are:

1. Would this be too difficult to manually write and implement?
2. Are there any existing solutions I can use?
3. Considering the website is almost done (structure/design have been built), should I switch to WordPress and use a plugin? I got 3/4 into converting the HTML into a theme, but I'd really prefer to continue this way

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't experience in javascript use third party plugin, like jQuery form: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files without a framework is made quite easy with w3's guide:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: I mean that I'm not using a framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation, but I'd gladly use one if it facilitates what I need--I just already have the layout and design covered.

Comment: fair enough, frameworks are are great for a lot of reasons, but I thought you just wanted to achieve a file upload portion of your form and script. The sample code in that resource could have your form uploading files in less than 5 minutes. Happy coding anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, I already have a custom PHP form that generates an email, but I'm not sure how to add an upload function, especially one of those "drag and drop" ones.